STM32F446RE SPI Communication With LSM6DS3 Not Working
I am attempting to communicate a write command to the LSM6DS3 however sometimes the MCU fails when checking to see if the TXE flag in the SPI1_SR is flipped or it will fail when putting data into the SPI1_DR.
C Code for Configuring SPI
void SPI1_INIT(void)
{
    // GPIO Initialization
    // PA5 is SCK, PA6 is MIS0, PA7 is MOSI
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= 1; // Enables GPIOA Clock

    GPIOA->MODER &= ~0xFC00; // Clears PA[5 : 7]
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0xA800; // Sets PA[5 : 7] to Alternate Function Mode
    
    GPIOA->AFR[0] &= ~0xFFF00000; // Clears AFR for PA[5 : 7]
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= 0x55500000; // Sets AFR for PA[5 : 7]
    
    GPIOA->OTYPER &= ~0x00E0; // Clears Output Type for PA[5 : 7], clear state is Push-Pull
    GPIOA->PUPDR &= ~0xFC00; // Clears PUPD for PA[5 : 7], clear state is no pull
    
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR &= ~0xFC00; // Clears Output Speed for PA[5 : 7]
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= 0xFC00; // Sets Ouptup Speed for PA[5 : 7] to High Speed
    
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~0x00030000; // Clears PA8 For CS
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0x00010000; // Sets PA8 to Output For CS
    GPIOA->ODR |= 1 << 8; // Makes PA8 High
    
    SPI1->CR1 |= 0x021F; // Configures SPI_CR1, CPOL and CPHA 1, so idle high and sample at rising edge
    SPI1->CR1 |= 0x0040; // Enables SPI_CR1
}

C Code for SPI Write Function:
void SPI_WRITE(uint8_t address, uint8_t data)
{
    GPIOA->ODR &= ~0x0100; // Make PA8 Low
    while(!(SPI1->SR & 0x2)) ; // able to transmit data?
    SPI1->DR = address | ~0x80; // When bit 8 is 0 is write
    while(!(SPI1->SR & 0x1)) ; // able to recieve data? 
    uint16_t temp = SPI1->DR << 8;
    
    while(!(SPI1->SR & 0x2)) ;
    SPI1->DR = data;
    while(!(SPI1->SR & 0x1)) ;
    temp |= SPI1->DR;
    GPIOA->ODR |= 0x0100; // Makes PA8 High
}

I am trying to call the SPI_WRITE function above like SPI_WRITE(0x13, 0x00); just to reset the control register but it does not work. I don't know why this is happening and am open for any advice on improvement.
I would prefer not using and SPI libraries for the STM32F446RE board but I am open to see how it would be done with a driver.
